# how to show uploaded image via Valums file uploader?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I started using [Andrew Valums File Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and it works as described, how to change it to show uploaded Picture in browser instead of uploaded filename and size?

I changed php.php accordingly to receive "filename" in JSON response. Now I need to parse JSON response and update HTML `<IMG>` attribute `'src'` in Javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution http://averoman.com/?p=14